# Creating an S4 class that contains a slot of the same type

Tags: r, oop

As practice, I'm creating a LinkedList implementation in R using S4 classes.

I have the following class:

```
setClass("node",

  slots = list(
    value = "numeric",
    next_node = "node"
  ),

  prototype = list(
    value = NA_real_,
    next_node = NA
  ) 
)
```

However, I'm getting the following error message:

```
Error in makePrototypeFromClassDef(properties, ClassDef, immediate, where) : 
  in making the prototype for class “node” elements of the prototype failed to match the corresponding slot class: next_node (class "node" )
In addition: Warning message:
undefined slot classes in definition of "node": next_node(class "node")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
setClass("node",

  slots = list(
    value = "numeric",
    next_node = "nullOrNode"
  ),

  prototype = list(
    value = NA_real_,
    next_node = NULL
  ) 
)

setClassUnion("nullOrNode", c("NULL", "node"))
```